Microsoft Entra ID: restrict 3rd-party app to access users data thata are in specific group
I need to assign access for third party app (MailStore Server) so it can access only users in MailStoreArchive group. I've tried "Assigment Required: yes", and I've assigned group MailStoreArchive to this app but I still see all users in MailStore Server app.
Most guides on the internet shows how to assign specific users to the app...
Simply speaking:
Bob is in group MailStoreArchive so MailStore Server can access Bob data,
Alice is not in group MailStoreArchive so MailStore Server cannot access Alice data and doesn't see her acoount on the list.
A don't have control over this third party app and how it's configured.

This really a vendor question.
But on general principles, with an EntraID app registration - which is what this would be using for mailbox access - you can't limit access to 365 objects like that.
It even says in the vendor doco:

MailStore Server ... must use Application Permissions to access user mailboxes in Microsoft 365. ...[O]n the Microsoft identity platform, ... this permission scope encloses the full level of privileges implied by a permission. As a consequence ... MailStore Server has access to all mailboxes in your Microsoft 365 tenant

To limit which user mailboxes are actually archived, it seems that you can scope which users are provisioned into the MailStore user database by group. It's described in their "Synchronizing User Accounts with Microsoft 365" doco, where the User Database Synchronization section specifically discusses group scoping.
To sum up, there are two pieces to the application integration as far as Entra/365 go:

Synchronising the specific users that will have their mail archived into the Mailstore user database for "registration" - this can be scoped by group. E.g. Selecting the MailStoreArchive group for user synchronisation - if the Mailstore user database doesn't have Alice registered in it, it won't archive Alice's mailbox.
The Mailstore application identity in EntraID that has permissions to actually archive the mail from the registered users' mailboxes. Due to limitations with EntraID/365, the application ID needs permissions to all the 365 mailboxes in the tenant - this is similar for any third party app. However, it won't be accessing mailboxes that aren't in scope according to the Mailstore registered users database (which is synced to and configured in their backend).

This is actually not too dissimilar to third-party apps in on-prem Exchange. Back in the day, vendors would recommend simply giving the appropriate "Recipient Management" or whatever role across the entire Exchange org to the application service account. The third-party application was then configured in its management console as to which mailboxes/whatever to target. I was once told I was "fussy" when I insisted on configuring permissions to a single database that contained the all the users for one app (Blackberry). EXO simply does not have databases you can target in that way.
The Mailstore vendor documentation seems to be very good - much, much better than most, if a little verbose. So, if the two articles I linked don't clarify things, I'd expect their customer support to be pretty helpful too.
If you don't have administrative access to the product, then someone in your organisation must, or a vendor who is managing the solution for you. They would need to be tasked to make any changes to limit the scope for synchronising the users into the Mailstore user DB to your nominated group.
